# Update Table at fixed interval of Time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table with 3 Columns: ID, Date and ColA

I want to write a Sql query which will update ColA with a value from another Table only after every 3 days else ColA value should be 0.

The Query should be grouped by ID.

```
Table 1

ID    Date           ColA
 1   2020/01/01      0
 1   2020/01/02      0
 1   2020/01/03      Run Update Query
 1   2020/01/04      0
 1   2020/01/05      0
 1   2020/01/06      Run Update Query
 2   2020/02/09      0
 2   2020/02/10      0
 2   2020/02/11      Run Update Query
 2   2020/02/12      0
 2   2020/02/13      0
 2   2020/02/14      Run Update Query
```

Any ideas?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select colA, row_number() over(partition by id order by date) rn
    from mytable
)
update cte 
set colA = case when rn % 3 = 0 then 'Run update query' else '0' end
```

The common table expression(aliased`cte`) ranks records having the same `id` by increasing `date`. Then, the outer query assigns the correct value depending on the rank.